# How to Block Request URL in C# Selenium ChromeDriver

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, google-chrome-devtools

I have following code to start an automated test software in Google Chrome driver.
I want to block some request in the page. (e.g `https://www.someurl.com/api/getdata`)

Manuelly, I can block the request in Developer Tools by `Right Click on the request` `->` `Block Request URL`.

How can I block the request url in the code?

```
ChromeDriverService service = ChromeDriverService.CreateDefaultService();
IWebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(service);

string url = "https://www.someurl.com";
driver.Navigate().GoToUrl(url);
```

Comment: The protocol has [Network.setBlockedURLs](https://chromedevtools.github.io/devtools-protocol/tot/Network/#method-setBlockedURLs) command so check Selenium's documentation: there'll be either a built-in method like this or there should be an ability to send a raw protocol command.

Comment: I downloaded to check selenium master project. I found this namespace which included some `setBlockedURLs` functions. Namespace path `OpenQA.Selenium.DevTools`. But there is no nuget package to include into project.

Comment: OpenQA.Selenium.DevTools is part of Selenium 4 I think. In Selenium 4 You would be able to something like DevTools devTools =  ((ChromeDriver)driver).getDevTools();

Comment: I think this link will be helpful for you https://raw.githubusercontent.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/master/dotnet/CHANGELOG    Also I think you can try the Selenium 4 .Net version by downloading the project from git but it can be unstable also https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/tree/master/dotnet